# Upgrade firmware on a Linksys/Cisco RV082 from Mac OS X client

Tags: cisco, configuration, router, linksys, cisco-vpn

I'm trying to upgrade the firmware on a [Linksys/Cisco RV082 router](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9926/index.html) using Mac OS X and it's not working. The current firmware version is 1.1.6.14 (Jul 28 2005 18:12:59), and I've tried upgrading to both 1.3.98-tm (Jun 20 2008 18:37:29) and 2.0.0.19-tm (Feb 20 2009 15:15:20).

#### Steps Taken to Try to Upgrade Firmware

1. Logged into the RV082's Web Management site using Safari
2. Navigated to System Management -> Firmware Upgrade
3. Select "Choose File" and select the desired firmware file
4. Select "Firmware Upgrade Right Now"
5. Waited for over 10 minutes without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various things, such as being directly connected to the RV082 instead of using wireless and disconnecting all other connections to the RV082 including the WAN connection to the Internet, I tried Firefox. Approximately two minutes after clicking "Firmware Upgrade Right Now", the RV082 rebooted and the firmware was updated.

Looks like Safari was the culprit.